# _wfopen_s error code when opening file to write in root folder (eg c:\temp.bin)

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, fopen

I have been passed an output file in the root folder (c:).

I am expecting to be returned EACCES(13) from _wfopen_s, this means that I can report some additional error information back to a user. This works fine on my machine.

The exe has then been tested on a different machine. EACCES is no longer return and this time EINVAL(22) is returned. On both machines the user running the exe has admin rights.

```
FILE * pFile = NULL;
errno_t err;
 
if (0 != (err = _wfopen_s (&pFile, outputFile.c_str(), L"wb")))
{
    MyErrorCode_t errcode = ((EACCES == err) ? ERR_OUTPUT_FILE_PERMISSON_DENIED : ERR_OUTPUT_FILE);
    ....
```

Is EINVAL expected?

Why would it behave differently machine to machine?

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return?  The underlying Windows call sets this and it might tell you more than `errno` does.

Comment: According to the [`_wfopen_s` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=vs-2019), `EINVAL` happens when at least 1 of the parameters is NULL, but that is not the case in the code shown (`c_str()` never returns NULL).

Comment: Um, yes.  If you're going to call `GetLastError()`, call `SetLastError(0)` before calling `_wfopen_s` to avoid reading a stale value.

Comment: Thank for the ideas, I will try 'SetLastError(0)'/'GetLastError' and see if provides any more information.

Comment: @PaulSanders `GetLastError` returns 1314,  A required privilege is not held by the client. Thank for your help

Comment: OK, seems reasonable, perhaps test for that then as well as whatever it returns on the other machine.